# <UncontrolledTooltip/> crashes Chrome while shown on a <Button/>

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, crash, tooltip

[SOLVED]
Reactstrap's tooltip:
`<UncontrolledTooltip target="myBtn">My Tooltip</UncontrolledTooltip>`
makes Google Chrome crash while used on:
`<Button id="myBtn">My Button</Button>`
MS Edge is working fine, so I don't know why it happens in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this elements in `<FormGroup/>` which had `onSubmit={event => event.preventDefault()`. The `preventDefault()` was calling every time I hovered `<Button/>` crashing web browser.
Solution: put your element out of the `<Form/>` or delete `<preventDefault()>`.